# How do these brothers feature twin features?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In S02E09 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*,

> it is revealed that Koenig guys are brothers rather than some kind of robots or clones. There are 13 Koenig brothers (out of which one is dead). All brothers are like twins except *twin* word isn't valid for them. Certainly, one mother can't give birth to 13 kids at a time.

How are they like twins?

Also, in the very end of last episode of season 1,

> New Koenig in main base said exact words in exactly the same way as his dead brother.

How could that be for a normal biological twin?

Comment: First, the tone of Koenig's scene indicated that he was joking that there were 13 "twins". Second, two siblings - or even people saying something with the same exact wording and tone proves absolutely nothing in either way.

Comment: There's only four of them, as revealed in season 4 episode 12 "hot potato soup."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was noted in a comment, there are not shown to be thirteen Koenig brother, but rather four, a set of quadruplets, probably identical (the odds of identical quadruplets are rare, [around 1 in 15 million, with about 73 recorded cases](https://www.today.com/health/mom-rare-identical-quads-reflects-sons-1st-year-amid-pandemic-t219944)) who further seem to have been encouraged to follow the same path.

> **LT Koenig**: "What happened to you? We had the same parents, same teachers, same liquor cabinet. Your brothers toughened up, joined the cause."

So, in short, there doesn't seem to be anything incredibly bizarre about them, just rare quadruplets, three of which took great pride in following the same path and acting the same.

Answer (score 7):

#### Potential Spoilers

> **[Unsubstantiated rumor](http://agentsofshield.wikia.com/wiki/Eric_Koenig) indicates that Eric Koenig may be a [Life Model Decoy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_Model_Decoy), explaining why there are 13 of him, and each of them being exactly alike in every way. We will have to wait for the next season to confirm the suspicion.**

- As you have stated, it would be highly unlikely they would be biological siblings with exactly the same appearance and the same age.
- Clones would work a lot better but they would be a huge expenditure in finances and would eventually differentiate over time depending on their experiences.

> The mostly likely candidates are LMD. They could wait until needed. They could be programmed with whatever information is required for their function. The bases would not need any living support staff with a tireless, yet roguishly handsome, automaton running it.

Comment: everyone's thought he was an LMD almost since the minute the second one showed up. But we also were all convinced that Coulson was an LMD so apparently Marvel fans just really like life model decoys. :)

Comment: But, all aren't 100% exactly alike. One brother was jerk type who recharging himself in weekend. Does it show some kind of malfunction?